# MailChimp Order Sync

Tags: magento2

i am using mailchimp ebizmart extension it was working before but some how its stop to sync order how i debug this issues.

Comment: Your request "how do I debug the issues" is too broad. You have not stated your Magento version.  You have not provided any clues as to the cause of the problem. Finally, there is professional help available from the developer of that extension at https://ebizmarts.com/contact-us - you should contact them first to request their help and only come back here if you didn't receive sufficient help.

Comment: i already did but they not reply

Comment: i just upload ebizmart extension few months back but not sure why its stop working suddenlh